# How to Import Data From Another Sheet If Any Data is Present In A Cell Range Corresponding to The Same Row

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am extremely basic in my understanding of coding formulas for Google Sheets, so please help where you can. The formula I'd like to put together is to search a vertical range (column) of information on a sheet and if there is any data present, I'd like the cells to automatically fill with the data of from the corresponding row of another vertical range within that same sheet.

For instance, I'd like my cell to search a range on a sheet (for this we can say the sheet is called 'Data Import') of Cells `L1:L`, and if there is any data present in that range, to import the data from the corresponding row of data in cells `C1:C`. I am sure this needs to be some kind of IF formulate possibly using `vlookup` or `importrange`, but I am not sure how to create the string for this. Ideally, this will results in a list of data from `C1:C` only if any data exists in the corresponding row for `L1:L` within the "Data Import" sheet.

I hope this makes sense! I can clarify further if needed!

Comment: To best get help, please share a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in row 1 of a free column:

```
=arrayformula( if( len('Data Import'!L1:L), 'Data Import'!C1:C, iferror(1/0) ) )
```

To omit values on rows where L1:L is blank, use this:

```
=filter('Data Import'!C1:C, len('Data Import'!L1:L))
```

Comment: This seems to have worked! It is importing, but it is importing EVERYTHING, even if the range is blank. Is there any way to omit the line if the cell range for hypothetical range L1:L is blank?

This way it is ONLY populating with information when data exists in that range? Also, if it isn't too much trouble, could you try to explain the logistics of how the formula works? I am really working to understand this and be more self sufficient. 

Again - thank you for your help!

Comment: Added an alternative formula that leaves out values in rows where L1:L is blank. If you need more help, please share a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data.

Comment: That worked! I really appreciate it! Thank you! 

Are you able to clarify how those formulas process so that I can work to use them in future work?

Comment: See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197), [Google Workspace Learning Center](https://gsuite.google.com/learning-center/products/sheets/) and [GFCGlobal](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/googlespreadsheets/creating-simple-formulas/1/). Also see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help with everything! I really appreciate it. As a follow up, if I wanted to make a formula for formula that can reference cells A1:A on my main sheet, and reference another sheet refer back to the "Data Import" sheet for the same value to exist. Ideally, this will generate a list of all the items that match A1:A with the corresponding data from the "Data Import" (let's stick with L1:L in "Data Import") that is in row with the information on C1:C of "Data Import" that matches A1:A from the main sheet. Thank you again!

Comment: That is different question, so please close this one first. Then create a new question, sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data.